# ZK - Check if an element has focus

Tags: java, zk

Does ZK support checking if an element has focus?

`HtmlBasedComponent` has both `focus()` and `setFocus(boolean)` to set the focus.. but I don't see any `getFocus()`.

Specifically, I am interested in checking the user's focus on an `InputElement`, a `Bandbox`; I want to know if the user is ready to type in the textbox part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method like `isFocus()` or `getFocus()`, but a workaround.
[`InputElement`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/impl/InputElement.html) has two events, `onFocus` and `onBlur`

```
public class MyInputElem extends InputElement{

  private boolean focus = false;

  @Listen("onFocus")
  public void focus(){
    focus = true;
  }

  @Listen("onBlur")
  public void blur(){
    focus = flase;
  }

  public boolean isFocus(){
    return focus;
  }
}
```

So if you extend from a `InputElement` like this, it should keep
the focus information up to date.

Comment: I ended up going with something like this, it does the trick. Cheers.